# RxJava: onErrorReturn cast problem when it returns a Set

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have a casting problem when I'm composing different RxJava operators,

Here is my method:

```
public Single<Set<User>> doWork() {
  return calculate() //
    .map(...) //
    .collect(HashSet<User>::new, Set::add) //
    .onErrorReturn(err -> {

      return new HashSet<User>();
    }).cast(Set.class);
}
```

This code actually compiles and run fine in Eclipse, but when build using Maven it gives the following compilation error:

```
Compilation failure incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) U
[ERROR]     (argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<java.util.Set> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends java.util.Set<com.util.user.User>>
```

I put the `.cast(Set.class)` because otherwise Eclipse fails to compile it.

I can't seem to satisfy the compilation so I may return `Set<User>` properly (If I remove the last `onErrorReturn` call than it compiles fine).

Any idea how to cast it right?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding another `map` call at the end of the chain instaed of the `cast`

```
public Single<Set<User>> doWork() {
  return calculate() //
  .map(...) //
  .collect(HashSet<User>::new, Set::add) //
  .onErrorReturn(err -> {

  return new HashSet<User>();
 }).map(user -> user);
}
```

Hope it helps anyone...